# Why does Visual Studio Premium 2010 not show all of the available project templates?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, web-applications, projects-and-solutions

I'm trying to create an ASP.NET Web Application, but this is all I see:

http://img832.imageshack.us/img832/8444/newproject1l.png
http://img837.imageshack.us/img837/3119/newproject2.png

I have confirmed that I have the full Visual Studio installed, not just Visual C#.
Why can't I see ASP.NET Web Application in the "new project" list?

Comment: Just a shot in the dark: what profile did you choose when starting VS for the first time ?

Comment: I have no idea. Are you referring to my Windows profile? If so, it would be the only profile on the machine. (That narrows it down ...) Oh wait, you mean what developer profile? C# for sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the interface it looks like the "Web Tools" section was unchecked while installing Visual Studio.  Try re-running the install, explicitly selecting Web Tools (can't remember the exact name) and seeing if that fixes the problem.

Comment: That was exactly the problem. My hard drive at work is tiny, so I had only selected C# on the install to conserve space. Re-running the installer to add the Visual Web-Developer tools fixes the problem.